# Second UipickerView doesn't load any data

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I am using two `UIPickerView` in the same ViewController. I need to load two different lists of  data in to those `UIPickerView`s. But I can load only for `uipickerView1` not for `UIPickerView2`

```
    -(void)viewDidLoad{
      pickerView1.delegate=self;
      pickerView2.delegate=self;
      pickerView1.tag=1;
      pickerView2.tag=2;
      // Here I've loaded dataArray1 and dataArray2
    }

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
    return 1;
}



-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    if(pickerView.tag==1)
    {
            return [dataArray1 count];
    }
    else if(pickerView.tag==1)
    {
        return [dataArray2 count];
    }

    return 1;
}


-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView*)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if(pickerView.tag==1)
    {
        if(row>0)
        {
        test1.text=[dataArray1 objectAtIndex:row];
        }else
        {
            test1.text=@"";
        }
    }
    else if(pickerView.tag==2)
    {
        if(row>0)
        {
            test2.text=[dataArray2 objectAtIndex:row];
        }
        else{
            test2.text=@"";
        }
    }

}

    -(NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView*)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
    {
        NSString* title=@"";
        if(pickerView.tag==1)
        {
            title= [dataArray1 objectAtIndex:row];
        }
        else if (pickerView.tag==2)
        {
            title= [dataArray2 objectAtIndex:row];
        }
        return title;
    }
```

I've checked `dataArray1` and `dataArray2`. Both are having 5 datas. But when viewController is loaded, only first picker loads all the data. For second one, only one data, which is in row index zero, has loaded. What is the mistake?

Comment: Show your picker creation code for two picker? Where did you assign tag to your picker? Did you add delegate for both pickers?

Comment: Thank you for your support and help. I think I've provided Enough code. I've used storyboard to create uipickerview. I think interface file is not needed to show. Then I've created data arrays in viewDidLoad itself. Here is the code where i've added delegate and tag. Here TitleForRow called only one time for uipickerView2 . What are all the codes do you need more ?

Comment: your question is faulty not clear what are you trying and also you have to asking question with explanation current.

Comment: I've edited my question. I hope, I've conveyed correctly.

Comment: could it be related to other UIPickerView's datasource methods you had to implement something like `–numberOfRowsInComponent` ?

Comment: that's very obvious! you are checking for tag==1 twice my friend! review `– numberOfRowsInComponent` and `else if` part! in fact for any picker view other than tag=1 you are returning 1!

Comment: Oh sad. What a big mistake I did with small mistake. :-( . Thank you @M.Porooshani

Comment: it happens to best of us too ;) don't worry about it and good luck

Answer (score -1):

There is problem in your `numberOfRowsInComponent` method

you are comparing only `pickerView.tag==1` in both condition

make change it to

```
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{

    if(pickerView.tag==1)
    {
            return [dataArray1 count];
    }
    else if(pickerView.tag==2)
    {
        return [dataArray2 count];
    }

    return 1;
}
```